# How to loop over loop in ansible and execute subsequent task when condition matches for each element if found

Tags: ansible

I have a use case where in vars/main.yaml I have defined server member as below and it is dynamic, sometimes vars will have 3 servers, sometimes it will be 4 and so:

```
server_name:
  - server1
  - server2
  - server3
```

I have a task which generates output as list of some server after fetching server from loadbalancer backend members as below:

```
    "ansible_facts": {
        "server_and_its_status": [
            "server1",
            "server1"
        ]
    },
```

I want to iterate the each and every server from vars/main.yaml with the list of servers generated as a part of tasks.
If server found, I want to perform some subseqent task and then move on to next server in vars/main.yaml and repeat if the server found in list of servers generated by task output.
I have tried below code which didnt help me :

```
    - name: Get the server details only for servers
      set_fact:
        server_and_its_status: "{{ jsondata1 | json_query('data.member[].nodes[].name') }}"

    - name: check if server is in list or not
      debug:
        msg: server {{ server_name }} found in list of servers generated by set_fact task 
      loop: "{{ server_name }}"
      loop: "{{ server_and_its_status  }}"
      when: item == server_name
```

Please suggest..

Answer (score 1):

As you want to iterate over the `servers` list, you only need to `loop` with it. There is no need to loop with `server_and_its_status`. There are tests such as `contains` or `in` to check if a particular text is present in the list items.

Using `in` for example:

```yaml
    - name: check if server is in list or not
      debug:
        msg: "server {{ item }} found in list generated by set fact"
      loop: "{{ servers }}"
      when: item in server_and_its_status
```